# NI CVI with Python

Tags: python, labview, labwindows, cvi

I'd like to integrate a Python IDLE-esque command prompt interface into an existing NI-CVI (LabWindows) application.  I've tried to follow the Python.org discussions but seem to get lost in the details.  Is there a resource out there for dummies like me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [python sample code calling a CVI](http://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-1494).

There are [DaqMx python bindings](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Data_Acquisition_with_PyUL) too.