# Embed Python in NI CVI(LabWindows)

Tags: python, swig, labwindows

I need to access LabWindows API and/or functions written in labwindows from Python.

My approach so far
I have been able to do so in Visual studio using SWIG to some extent, but my dll creation fails when i try to generate it in Labwindows using the source file and the SWIG generated wrapper file.

Comment: Can you report the precise nature of the failure (e.g. the specific error message)?

Comment: it does not find header files like io.h and stdio.h so i include the vc/include to the include directories and it still gives 20 odd built error. like this link http://forums.ni.com/ni/board/message?board.id=180&thread.id=29708

Answer (score 0):

These links are essentially pointing to the same answer.  Hope it is helpful...

http://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-1494

[NI CVI with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91666/ni-cvi-with-python)